# Puppeter get first visible button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

I have two buttons on a page, sometimes the first is visible, sometimes the second, sometimes both are visible.

I want to select the last visible button, and click on it.

```
<div class="button-area">
   <a class="button">first</a>
   <a class="button hide">second</a>
</div>
```

For example here: the "second" button.

I tried with:

```
var btnSelector='.button-area .button:visible:last';
await page.waitForSelector(btnSelector, { timeout: 6000 });
var [btn] = await page.$(btnSelector);
await Promise.all([
  btn.click(),
  page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
]);
```

But it doesn't work, it seems that my selector is not correctly handled :/

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Means that no button is found by this selector

Comment: Those aren't `button`s, those are `a`s. Maybe `a.button:not(.hide)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a try.

```
(async () => {
  let browser, page;
  let url = 'https://example.com';

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });
    await page.waitForSelector('.button-area .button', { visible: true, timeout: 60000 });

    const buttonElement = await page.$('.button-area .button');
    if (await buttonElement.isIntersectingViewport()) {
      buttonElement.click();
      page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
})();
```

Or you can try it this way.

```
(async () => {
  let browser, page;
  let url = 'https://example.com';

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });
    const buttonElement = await page.waitForSelector('.button-area .button', { visible: true, timeout: 60000 });
    await buttonElement.click();
    await page.waitForNavigation();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
})();
```

And if none of them work you could try.

```
(async () => {
  let browser, page;
  let url = 'https://example.com';

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000 });
    await page.waitForSelector('.button-area .button', { visible: true, timeout: 60000 });
        
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button-area .button')).filter((buttons) => {
        return buttons.className != 'button hide'
      }).forEach(button => {
        if (button) button.click();
      });
    });

    await page.waitForNavigation();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
      console.log('closing browser');
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: You are welcome. I thought the third method would've been the one to work.

Comment: The third one had a mistake in the code I fixed it so you can also try that one now if you want.